# Transfer google documents to account in another domain

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I need transfer some google accounts from domain1.com to domain2.com. Also I need trasfer all google document at this accounts, with their permissions. Can i make it using google drive api. I don't find any methods for this operation. Primary i need transfer file permissions. Is there a possibility for this type operations.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to transfer the file ownership between domains that are not in the same panel. a possible troubleshooting is to make a copy of the files.